# Generate better names with no module

Tags: python, string, random

I created a script that will generate random names with no library. I created a few perimeters that it must follow such as no name should have three vowels or consonants in a row or a name should not have two of the same vowels or consonants in a row because this can damage many names. So the names I get are names but really odd and weird:

```
mulaku
--------
keorah
--------
oslouv
--------
macaog
--------
oavsut
--------
lnoufi
--------
tkamio
--------
iodecs
--------
ohihto
--------
iufuct
--------
Joskitso
```

Some of these names just straight up can't be pronounced. "lnoufi"??? Does any one know a couple of ideas towards making my name look and sound more like a name. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import string
import random
def Gen():
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:-4].replace('q','')
    letters = letters.replace('j','')
    passed = False
    while passed == False:
        vowels = 3
        consanants = 3
        consanantCount = 0
        vowelCount = 0
        VowelMany = 0
        VowelManyFinal = None
        ConManyFinal = None
        ConMany = 0
        reps = 1
        name = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(vowels+consanants))
        name = ''.join(['' if i>reps-1 and e==name[i-reps] else e for i,e in enumerate(name)])
        for letter in name:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                vowelCount +=1
            else:
                consanantCount +=1
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                VowelMany +=1
                if VowelMany > 2:
                    VowelManyFinal = True
            else:
                VowelMany = 0

            if letter in 'bcdfghjklmnprstv':
                ConMany+=1
                if ConMany > 2:
                    ConManyFinal = True
            else:
                ConMany = 0
        if vowelCount == vowels and consanantCount == consanants and VowelManyFinal != True and ConManyFinal != True:
            passed = True
        else:
            passed = False
            
    return name
for i in range(10):
    print(Gen())
    print('--------')
```

Comment: perhaps make some rules that make the words make more sense..i.e. for consonants only 'ch' or 'sh' etc. are valid options..same with vowels and vowel/consonant pairs/trips/etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying to use a list of common names as input to a randomization process. For example, one large list of names is available [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3201/files/NAMES.TXT).

One approach would simply be to break the names into pieces, and randomly recombine them. Here's one simple implementation, which effectively weights various character combinations simply by keeping lists that may contain duplicates:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import choice, randint

starts = []
middles = defaultdict(list)
ends = []

# Read through a list of names
with open('names.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for name in infile:
        name = name.lower().strip()

        # Keep track of all the beginnings
        starts.append(name[:3])

        # Lookup table of next characters
        for i in range(len(name) - 3):
            middles[name[i:i+2]].append(name[i+2])

        # Keep track of all the endings
        ends.append(name[-2:])

for _ in range(20):

    # Randomly choose a start of a name
    name = choice(starts)

    # Randomly insert some middle characters based upon what we already have
    for _ in range(randint(0, 2)):
        name += choice(middles.get(name[-2:], ['']))

    # Randomly choose the end of a name
    name += choice(ends)

    # See what we got
    print(name.title())
```

And the list of names that I got:

```
Pophita
Perst
Osbail
Venctno
Cyntne
Clast
Progie
Nadrich
Emaan
Ruser
Darna
Tallett
Casier
Zithan
Brune
Noble
Shude
Katiend
Donnda
Valoe
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.

You can make use of *Markov chains* to get "pronounceable names".  A [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) models one or more states (for example, individual letters or syllables), and stores the probabilities to transition from one state to another (e.g., "b" to "e" with a chance of 20 percent, or "b" to "b" with a chance of 1 percent).  Note that Markov chains are designed to have no memory of the past except for its current state.  (See also my section on [Markov chains](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Markov_Chains).)

In your case, the states consist of sensible syllables (which are a better basis for generating pronounceable words than letters are).

The following implements a simple syllable generator using Markov chains (you can adapt the states and the weights in the transition matrix to your needs).

```
import random

transitions = {
"ka":[[20,"ga"],[30,"ma"],[30,"mu"],[30,"ba"],[5,"ka"]],
"ga":[[1,"ga"],[30,"ma"],[30,"mu"],[30,"ba"]],
"ma":[[20,"ga"],[30,"ma"],[30,"ka"],[30,"ba"]],
"ba":[[20,"ga"],[30,"ka"],[30,"mu"],[5,"ba"]],
"mu":[[20,"ka"],[30,"ma"],[1,"mu"],[30,"ba"]],
}

# First state
state=random.choice(list(transitions.keys()))
print(state)
# Next three states
for i in range(3):
   tr=transitions[state]
   w=[x[0] for x in tr]
   state=random.choices(tr,weights=w)[0][1]
   print(state)
```